# MySQL Installer for Netbeans 8.0.1

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I guess this is a very basic question but it stucked me for two days.

I am new to Java and creating a webapp in Netbeans 8.0.1. Static app get created easily. For Db based app, I require MySQL installation. Earlier I believed that MySQL server is there inside Netbeans 8.0.1, kindly confirm if it is right?

Also I found number of MySQL installers but no free version is configuring correctly because of disabled options. If MySQL server is mandatory for WebApp in Java following Netbeans 8.0.1, can I get a recommendation for any stable MySQL installer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can find the links to install all of the MySQL server or management tools here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/

You can use the `MySQL Installer` to easily install the tools that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Following https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/install-and-configure-mysql-server.html for installation of MySQL server. Getting error while authentication. Is there any default password of MySQL for windows?

Comment: The default username is `root` and there is no default password.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html)
I downloaded mqsql from this link and it works fine with eclipse.